# What's the difference for sizeof in C to calculate char a[] and char *a?

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    char a[] = "Love you!";
    char *b = "Love you!";

    printf("%s\n", a); 
    printf("Length: %d\n", sizeof(a));

    printf("%s\n", b); 
    printf("Length: %d\n", sizeof(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Look at the above code.

Here's the output:

```
Love you!
Length: 10
Love you!
Length: 8
```

I understand **char a[] = "Love you!"** which has 10 characters with an invisible '\0' at the end.

What I don't get is length for char *b is only 8 while the characters in it can be printed perfectly.

**What's the difference for sizeof in C to calculate char a[] and char *a ?**

Comment: Maybe you incorrectly have a memory model of "array" as actually being an array plus a pointer. But there is no pointer, just the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are different things.

`char a[] = "Love you!"` is just syntax sugar for `char a[10] = "Love you!"`. It creates a variable, which is an array of ten objects of type `char`. So `sizeof a` will give you the size of 10 `char`s.

`char *b = "Love you!"` creates one variable, which is a pointer, and makes it point to a the first character of the string literal `"Love you!"`. So `sizeof b` will give you the size of one pointer to `char`.

Comment: …and the size of one pointer will be 8 bytes (64 bits) on a 64-bit system. If you compiled and ran this code on a 32-bit system, `sizeof b` would be 4.

Comment: Possibly. But keep in mind that even in a single system, pointers to different types could have different sizes.

Comment: @HarryCutts  re [sizeof b would be 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213851/whats-the-difference-for-sizeof-in-c-to-calculate-char-a-and-char-a#comment91377174_52213877) :The `n` in an `n`-bit system far more often describes the native integer processing width than the pointer size.  Many systems do use equal size native integer and pointer - so makes no difference there.  Yet when they differ the `n` is usually not the pointer size, but native integer width.